# Update row that is hidden due to pagination/sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I execute a `fnUpdate` operation on a row that is currently out of view due to pagination?

I'm developing a web app that uses two DataTable instances in different div containers. When one container is visible, the other is hidden via `jQuery.fadeOut()`/`fadeIn()`

In one div, I have a summary table that shows a selection of the data fields that are available in the other, hidden, container. The rows between these tables are mapped via a `_id#` suffix to the row ID, For example, row id `4_performance_3` in the summary table maps to row id `timeline_task_3` in the full detail table.

If row id `timeline_task_3` is not visible due to pagination and/or sorting, how can I update the row if I've applied changes to `4_performance_3`?

In the code snippet, `element` is null due to the row id being out of view via pagination

```
var tableArray = timelineTable.fnGetNodes();
var elemSplit;

for (var i = 0; i < tableArray.length; i++) {
    elemSplit = tableArray[i].id.split("_");

    if (elemSplit[2] == currentTask.id){
        element = document.getElementById(tableArray[i].id);

        timelineTable.fnUpdate(currentTask.internal, element, 0, false);
        timelineTable.fnUpdate(currentTask.dueDate, element, 1, false);
        timelineTable.fnUpdate(currentTask.label, element, 4, false);
        timelineTable.fnUpdate(currentTask.complete, element, 6, false);
        timelineTable.fnUpdate(currentTask.comments.length, element, 7, false);

        timelineTable.fnSort([[1, "asc"]]);

        console.log("updated timeline tasks");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the hidden table might not have selectable nodes... but it sure has it's own data!

The easiest way is to hold a reference to the two tables:

```
var mySummary = $('#exampleSum').dataTable();
var myTimeline = $('#exampleLine').dataTable();
```

Now you can always get to the data of each table with myTimeline.fnGetData(). Maybe you need to add an extra invisible data column so you can more easily reference to between the two tables.
The fnUpdate() function also works with the indexes from fnGetData().

I'm not sure, but maybe you have to call a myTimeline.fnDraw() right before or after the table becomes visible again to trigger to display the new data.